# Connecting with an IP address and IP subnet?

Tags: html, curl, ip, ip-address

I am looking to connect with these addresses but I am unsure of where to start. I've been given this IP address: 65.51.180.122 and this IP subnet(which I've changed for posting purposes): 47.19.102.176/28. I've looked at this answer in [How to access IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043602/how-to-access-site-through-ip-address-when-website-is-on-a-shared-host). Yet when I used the answers given I received a "This webpage is not available error". I decided to use a more well-known address for testing, facebook, and received the same error. Seeing the webpage is not necessary, simply accessing the data on it via an curl request in my Mac Terminal would work.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to set up af HTTP server - or am I wrong? Which devices do you want to connect and what is your aim?

Comment: I'm working with a company that has given me this IP address and IP subnet from their ISP. They are staging and production environments where I will pulling data from an API.

Comment: Oh okay. When you open it in your browser (which is what you've done?) the default port would be 80. You might want the port from the company to access the API on the right socket. Which port are you using from curl?