# How to access shared hosting website by ip address

Tags: php, dns, ip-address, web-hosting

I just start learn to create website. I create a free shared hosting (Hostinger) and uploaded my website . I can access my site by domain name but i dont known how to do it with the ip address they gave me.

```
> -My Domain name: mywebsitename.esy.es
> -IP: 31.170.167.204
> -Username: u935348985
> -SERVER IP: 31.170.167.195
```

Here is the question again: How can i access my web by the ip they gave me, not by domain name? THANK.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043602/how-to-access-site-through-ip-address-when-website-is-on-a-shared-host

Answer (score 8):

If you're using shared hosting, making a HTTP request to the IP alone is not enough, as the server does not know which site you're looking for. Alongside the request, you must include the `Host` header, with your domain included.

By default, a browser will do this from the URL you provide it - so it will obviously be empty if accessing by an IP address. Depending on your browser, you can use various extensions to manually set the headers as required.

Answer (score 4):

Generally you can access in shared hosting website using IP or DNS address by you have to add **~** sign before your username in below format

`http://<server_ip_or_dns>/~<your_username>`,

If its not working then you have to contact your web administrator.

Comment: Which one? http://31.170.167.195/~u935348985  or  http://31.170.167.204/~u935348985 or http://31.170.167.195/~mywebsitename ? Ijust check, None of it work.

Comment: @dante, then contact your web administrator. :) because all web hosting provides this facility for access without domain by using ip address and username

Comment: @HareshVidja This seems to work for me and I can access my shared hosting space. Is this the IP address I use for setting A records e.g. 143.95.38.226/~ariescom
?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to access your website with a testing URL. Use the below site and enter your server and domain details there.

https://hosts.cx/

This will create a temporary URL.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Gareth, you can use a software like [PostMan](https://www.postman.com/) to simulate a request to your host. Just use a GET request with your server's IP address, then:

- Click on Headers
- Uncheck `Host` header
- Add a new `Host` header and specify your domain name as value
- Then Send your request